# How to create GraphQL Child Resolvers with Lambda

Tags: aws-lambda, graphql, aws-appsync

I'm trying to create a mutation that calls a child resolver in addition to the parent resolver if an optional parameter is sent in.

I'm using AWS AppSync to sent my queries to Lambda. AppSync creates and sends an `AppSyncEvent` to my resolver file that looks something like this:

```
{
"info": {
        "parentTypeName": "Mutation",
        "selectionSetList": [
            ...
        ],
        "selectionSetGraphQL": "...",
        "fieldName": "updateUser",
        "variables": {}
    }
}
```

This event gets passed to my lambda function where, based on the `fieldName` and `parentTypeName`, I call my `updateUser` function.

I have the below schema

```
schema {
  query: Query
  mutation: Mutation
}

type Query {
  getUser(id: ID!): User
}

type Mutation {
  updateUser(name: String, email: String, bookRead: BookReadInput): User
}

type User {
   name: String
   email: String
   booksRead: [Book]
}

type Book {
   title: String
   author: String
}

type BookReadInput {
   title: String
   author: String
}
```

I want that if the mutation gets passed `bookRead` then it will know to call a child resolver called `addBook` besides for the regular `updateUser` resolver.

I've seen various articles about implementing child resolvers but I can't figure out how they can work with lambda and the way my resolvers work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The lambda could inspect the selectionSetList and decide what to do with the BookReadInput fields.
See https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mobile/appsync-and-the-graphql-info-object/

You could also go with pipeline resolvers to first update the user, and then add the book.

I don't think there is a way to have it automated. You need to set it up, one way or the other.

Comment: SelectionSetList wouldn't work for a mutation unless you require that you always have to return books if you update books. If it needs to be set up then I guess I can just check event.arguments to see if book was sent in.